# Looping through JSON data using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson, squarespace

I'm trying to get specific information from a JSON file (Squarespace) with the aim of appending it to a `<div>`. I need to loop through the data and get the location from each post. This is the code I'm using:

```
$.getJSON("http://www.theluxedit.com/?format=json-pretty", function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, value) {
        $('.locationData').append(data.items.location.addressLine2);
    });
});
```

It will only work if I specifiy the item using an integer, such as:

```
$('.locationData').append(data.items[1].location.addressLine2);
```

This seems to be working for other examples I've tried, am I maybe getting the JSON concatenation wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is you need to iterate through the items themselves rather than the entire object returned:

```
var $locationData = $('.locationData');
$.getJSON("http://www.theluxedit.com/?format=json-pretty", function(data) {
    $.each(data.items, function(index, item) {
        $locationData.append(getLocationEl(item.location.addressLine2));    
    });
});

function getLocationEl(address) {
    return $('<div>', { text: address });
}
```

By doing this, each iteration will look at a different item. You can then access properties on that item directly, rather than from the top-level data returned.

Also, I am assuming this is being run on theluxedit.com. Otherwise you will get an error. See this for more info: ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)

Comment: Just as an aside comment, its inefficient to do a complete DOM search for a class inside the loop.. store the result in a variable before the loop and use the reference.

Comment: Updated the answer. If you want the text to be on separate lines, this works well. You could also use a span instead of a div. Additionally, you could just accumulate all the values and append them as comma-separated list in a single string.